# Shell script read file, output is garbled code

Tags: shell

environment: OS X El Capitan + terminal

my script is  below:

```
    #!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    echo "LINE:"$line
done < fileName
```

my source file is below:

```
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_groupon_menu@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_individual_logo@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_list_mail@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_log_gry@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_log_pen@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_logo_share@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_pig_a@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_price_five.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_price_four.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_ring_empty@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_ring_full@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_set_up@2x.png
./Resources/Images/tmp/ic_share_green@2x.png
```

output is below:

```
LINE:??.
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
LINE:
```

I can't find any meaningful word.I try to slove this issue end with puzzling.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Outputting a binary file in a terminal window will produce garbled text.

Comment: Read a .txt file and print line by line.Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer.The source file is UTF-16 encoding, UTF-16 is different from UTF-8.

the command for view  file encoding:

```
 file  pathToFile
```

the command for convert file encode:

```
 iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 originFile > destinationFile
```